# Create file with double quotes in values

Tags: ansible

I need to create a file with double quotes in the values.

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    test_var:
      - hostname: "hostname"
        hardware:
          - disk: "HDD 50G"
            ram: "5G"
            cpu: "4 Cores"
        users:
          - user: "user"
            passwd: "sdf%^#("
            email: "user@domain.com"
            groups: "group1, group2, group3"

  tasks:
    - name: Creating temporary file
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
            {{ test_var | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
        dest: "./test_file"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I want to get:

```
- hardware:
  - cpu: "4 Cores"
    disk: "HDD 50G"
    ram: "5G"
  hostname: "hostname"
  users:
  - email: "user@domain.com"
    groups: "group1, group2, group3"
    passwd: "sdf%^#("
    user: "user"
```

But i get:

```bash
$ cat test_file
- hardware:
  - cpu: 4 Cores
    disk: HDD 50G
    ram: 5G
  hostname: hostname
  users:
  - email: user@domain.com
    groups: group1, group2, group3
    passwd: sdf%^#(
    user: user
```

How do add quotes?

Comment: Can you explain why you want the quotes in the YAML file? The two files are exactly equivalent, and will de-serialize to exactly the same data structure.

Comment: For example, values can contain lines with commas or special characters (passwords, mailboxes).

Comment: Then they would be quoted properly without any changes required on your part.

Comment: agree, the configuration file is processed correctly

Comment: If you want to close your question please don't edit it into the question. Instead, either post it as an answer and accept it, or.delete your question.

Comment: i would suggest that you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/yaml-do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml as it is similar or the same question you already have.

Answer (score 1):

The filter `to_nice_yaml` uses PyYAML and all arguments [are passed to the `dump()` function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json), so you can use all its arguments.

`default_style='"'` looks promising.

Result for `to_nice_yaml(indent=2, default_style='"')`:

```yaml
- "hardware":
  - "cpu": "4 Cores"
    "disk": "HDD 50G"
    "ram": "5G"
  "hostname": "hostname"
  "users":
  - "email": "user@domain.com"
    "groups": "group1, group2, group3"
    "passwd": "sdf%^#("
    "user": "user"
```